# How to keep all items in an ExtJS treepanel visible at all times

Tags: extjs

I have a treepanel listing a complex hierachy of nodes.

If the list of nodes gets too big then the panel scrolls which is desired.

What is not desired is the ability of a user to click the arrow (or dblclick the item) to expand/collapse parent nodes.

What is the simplest way to ensure a treepanel always renders fully expanded and the expand/collapse functionality is removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once needed to do this, and this solution(found [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136633-Make-a-node-in-a-Ext.tree.TreePanel-permanently-expanded-and-non-collapsible)) worked for me:

For each uncollapsible node:

```
{text: 'Node', nodeType: 'node', expanded: true, cls: 'uncollapsible', collapsible: false}
```

In your CSS:

```
.uncollapsible .x-tree-elbow-minus {
    background-image: url(resources/images/default/tree/elbow.gif);
}

.uncollapsible .x-tree-elbow-end-minus {
    background-image: url(resources/images/default/tree/elbow-end.gif)
}
```

in your TreePanel:

```
listeners: {
    beforecollapsenode: function(node) {
        return node.attributes.collapsible;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! clean solution and does what i need